# HTTPHandler in asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement HTTPHandler in my asp.net project. I followed the links to do the same. I created a folder named App_code in my root. Them I wrote a class MyHTTPHandler. 
It has the Reusable property on, also I handles the Process

```
public class HelloWorldHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public HelloWorldHandler()
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        if (context.Request.RawUrl.Contains(".cspx"))
        {
            string newUrl = context.Request.RawUrl.Replace(".cspx", ".aspx");
            context.Server.Transfer(newUrl);
        }

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        // To enable pooling, return true here.
        // This keeps the handler in memory.
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

The Handler is not getting fiered. As I am new to ASP.Net I m not able to figure out, what is going wrong. I also entered the part that is required in web.config. I went through many links, some says you need to copy the code in IIS. I am not able to understand it. 
Please advice

Comment: How to register http handler: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: It seems Microsoft uses Cassini server to run the development projects. If I make my code run on IIS will this solve my problem. From the above given link I found this steps.    Open Visual Studio or Visual Web Developer.

    In the File menu, click New Web Site.

    In the Location list, select HTTP and then enter "http://localhost/HttpHandler" in the text box.

    Click OK.

Comment: I will be grateful if I get any help in this regard, as I am really stuck and not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any set up in IIS, unless you want to handle some path that is already regsistered. In general case all you need to do is to add the `<httpHandlers>` section to web.config:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*"
           path="HelloWorldHandler.ashx" 
           type="NamespaceName.HelloWorldHandler, WebApplicationName" />
    </httpHandlers>
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Here `HelloWorldHandler.ashx` is a path that you need to use to fire the handler, `NamespaceName.HelloWorldHandler` is a full name of the handler class, including all namespaces, and `WebApplicationName` is the name of the assembly handler is implemented in.

Comment: I also had another question. What makes the difference if I do my task in HTTPModule instead of HTTPHandler. Does that makes any difference. I can rewrite my URL in HTTPModule also. Then why do we need HTTPHandler. Anyways the reuest has to pass through the HTTPModule and then will  get processed by the  HTTPHandler. Am I going wrong in understanding the concept.

Comment: @sanchaita, your understanding is right, request goes through module (or several modules) and is processed in handlers. Basically modules give you access to the request pipeline and allow to decide what actions to perform. While handlers are the actions themselves. Operations like markup rendering (all Pages are handlers btw) and file downloading are supposed to be done by handlers, while something like authorization is a job for module.

Comment: I googled for HTTPModule, I implemneted, it was still not working. Then again after doing google I found a link which says to create the object of HTTPModule in global.aspx. On doing same I could achieve the URL redirecting through HTTPModule. Am I doing the right thing. Am I supposed to do the same for HTTPHandler so that it works.